# how can i make the burger icon bigger in my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i cant seem to figure out how to make the burger icon bigger in my flutter app

[image: n my]

**here is the code for my flutter app, i am simply trying to make it bigger.....................................................................................................................................................**

```
return new Scaffold(

  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0.0,
          iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),

  ),
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
       
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header', ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Trip History',style : TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,fontFamily:"Clan-Medium")),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Payment',style : TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,fontFamily:"Clan-Medium")),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Settings',style : TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,fontFamily:"Clan-Medium")),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help you without a reproducible code? Without the code I can say change size of the icon

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: where is that icon... I can not see it in your code!

Answer (score 0):

Change your AppBar to this and then focus on the `size` property of the Icon, Change it as you want.

```
appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0.0,
    iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
    leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
                   Icons.menu,
                   color: Colors.black,
                   size: 24.0,
                  ),
        onPressed: (){
           _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
        },
   )
),
```

You can set any icon here.

Also, as the [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/leading.html#material.AppBar.leading.1) say, you can use it as well which also has an option to set `ToolTip`.

```
AppBar(
  leading: Builder(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
        onPressed: () { Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); },
        tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
      );
    },
  ),
)
```